# Writing query to calculate average revenue but getting a group by error?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Table #1:

```
create table Program_T
    (AccountName varchar(150) not null unique,
    ProgramID int not null,
    Revenue int,
    Advocates int,
    Shares int,
    Conversions int,
    Impressions int,
    LaunchDate date,
    CSMID int not null,
    constraint Program_PK primary key (AccountName, CSMID),
    constraint Program_FK1 foreign key (AccountName) references Account_T(AccountName),
    constraint Program_FK2 foreign key (CSMID) references CSM_T(CSMID));
```

Table #2:

```
create table Account_T
    (AccountName varchar(150) not null unique,
    Health varchar(10) not null,
    EcommercePlatform varchar(50),
    CSMID int not null,
    Industry varchar(50),
    Amount int not null,
    constraint Accounts_PK primary key (AccountName),
    constraint Accounts_FK foreign key (CSMID) references CSM_T(CSMID));
```

I am trying to write a query that will give us the Average revenue, ordered by each Ecommerce platform.

So far I have....

```
Select Revenue, EcommercePlatform
From Program_T, Account_T
Where Avg(Revenue)
Order by EcommercePlatform;
```

But I am getting an error that says:

> Invalid Use Of Group Function" but I am not even using a group
>   function.

Please advise

Comment: Avg is a group function (it's also the only function in this query)

Comment: You need a sub-query for that `Avg(Revenue)` value.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: I tried to use join syntax and it is giving me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, the code should look something like the following:

```
Select Avg(Revenue), EcommercePlatform
From Program_T inner join Account_T on Program_T.AccountName=Account_T.AccountName
group by EcommercePlatform;
```

This should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select a.EcommercePlatform, Avg(p.Revenue)
grom Program_T p join
     Account_T a
     using (accountName)
group by a.EcommercePlatform;
```

Notes:

- Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Qualify all column references, especially when more than one table is referenced in the query.
- Columns you want to select go in the `select` clause, not the `where` clause.